# Migrate Rails Base Table, Table name containing *

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I have an active record in model called "base_transaction_log.rb".

It's schema information is:

```
# Table name: *_bank_transaction_logs
#
#  All bank transaction tables should have the same format.
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  credit          :decimal(8, 2)
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
```

I wish to change one of the column, credit, to use decimal(16,2).

So I created a migration file and added these lines in the change function.

```
change_column :*_bank_transaction_logs, :credit, :decimal, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
```

This does not work.

Syntax Error (rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/seokhoonlee/Desktop/db/migrate/20160607080159_increase_rest_decimal_precision.rb:81: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...column :*_bank_transaction_logs, :debit, :decimal, :precisio...)

```
change_column :base_transaction_logs, :credit, :decimal, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
```

This does not work too.

Name Error (Mysql2::Error: Table 'development.base_transaction_logs' doesn't exist)

How can I migrate a table in the database when the table is a base table(?, I don't know such term exists) or its table name contains *?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of wildcard was used to subclass the Active Record but was not backed by DB (it does not exist in the database).

So therefore, it could not find the appropriate table in the database.

For my case, I had to take care of *_bank_transaction_logs by migrating on any files that contains bank_transaction_logs (eg. ABC_bank_transaction_logs).

Comment: Also some user posted an answer and deleted it told me to escape special characters with single quote. If you happen to have special characters in your table name, do surround it with single quote!